# AngularJS Run a function when visiting on a different page

Tags: angularjs

I just want to know what is the best practice for AngularJS if i want to run a function if the user goes to this page.

So for example. i have this url
http://localhost:3000/post/58fc0449a467230cb003151d
It will show the post with that ID. So the way i show it is, on the page, im using ng-init="function()" so that everytime the user goes to this page it will initialize the function first, which is, that function calls to the backend and returns me the data that i need.

So my question is, is this the best approach/practice on this one? Using ng-init to call the function then show the data to the view?

**UPDATE

Thanks for the answers! By the way im using a controller for this one, my function resides on the controller. i'll paste my code here..
The code here shows the messages by the users retrieved from the database

**Messages.htm**

```
<div ng-controller="MessageController as mc" ng-init="messageGet()" class="container" style="height: 90vh">
<h1>Messages</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="media-list" ng-repeat="messages in theMessages">
            <a href="#"> 
                <li class="media card-1">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="/public/images/matt.jpg" alt="avatar">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h5 class="media-heading" ng-if="messages.user1 !== username">{{messages.user1}}</h5>
                        <h5 class="media-heading" ng-if="messages.user2 !== username">{{messages.user2}}</h5>
                        <strong>Topic: </strong>{{messages.postname}}
                        <h5><strong>{{messages.recentmessage.sender}}</strong>: {{messages.recentmessage.message}}  </h5>
                        <div>
                        <a href="/messages/{{messages._id}}" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-bottom: 10px">View message</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**MessageController**

```
var app = angular.module('main');

app.controller('MessageController', ['$rootScope','MessageService', '$scope', '$localStorage', 'mySocket', '$location', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, MessageService, $scope, $localStorage, mySocket, $location, $stateParams){
   $scope.currentUrl = $location.$$path;   
   var vm = this;

    $scope.messageGet = function(){
        var result = MessageService.getMessages()
            .then(function(result){
                $scope.theMessages = $localStorage.messages;
                $scope.username= $localStorage.username;
            });
    };
```

**MessageService**

```
var app = angular.module('main');

app.service('MessageService', ['$http', '$localStorage', function($http, $localStorage){

    var vm = this;

    vm.getMessages = function(){
        var getmessage = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/getmessages',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {
                userid: $localStorage.userid
            }
        };

        return $http(getmessage)
            .then(function(response){
                $localStorage.messages = response.data.info;
                return true;
            });
    };
```

So as you can see, when i go to the url `localhost:3000/messages` it will load the Messages.htm template then i will run the function "messageGet()" because i need to get the messages from the database then display it on my view. If i will not use ng-init, then how will i run the function when the user visits this specific url?

**2nd Update**

So i tried to get rid of the ng-init function, i used an Immediately-Invoked Function

MessageController

```
(function messageGet (){
    console.log('Messaged run!');
    var result = MessageService.getMessages()
        .then(function(result){
            $scope.theMessages = $localStorage.messages;
            $scope.username= $localStorage.username;
        });
})();
```

So everytime the Message.htm is loaded, this function is ran.

My question is, will this do? instead of ng-init?

Thank you!

Comment: 'Best practice' is to use router module for that. ng-init is recommended for literally nothing, it just results in lousy code and nothing else.

Comment: Is the messageGet function part of the controller?

Comment: yes the messageGet function is inside the MessageController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @georgeawg stated you should use the designated controller for this kind of actions.
If you're using angular version >= 1.5 you should use the controller property $onInit for it.
Read more about the angular component and their life cycles [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

If you're using an older version you can do the following:

```
function MyController() {
     function init() {
     //enter init code here
     }

     init();
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#user-content-resolving-promises).

Comment: Thank you! i updated my question. i uploaded my code, the function that im initializing is residing on the controller.

Answer (score 3):

*im using `ng-init="function()"` so that everytime the user goes to this page it will initialize the function first*

That use of `ng-init` is not recommended. Use controllers for that.

From the Docs:

> ### ngInit
>
> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`, such as for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat` as seen in [[this demo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#example)]; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use [controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.
>
> [— AngularJS ngInit Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)